# Code Igniter form validation and file upload?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, validation

I have a file upload as part of my form,

I am using the code igniter form validation library,

I am also using the code igniter upload library,

I know how to upload images etc using the upload library but I want to include basic validation of the file during the form validation (e.g. required, maxsize, filetype).

I get that I will need to do a callback but the issue is that the validation library only checks `$_POST` it does not check `$_FILES`

How can I do this?

I was thinking perhaps to copy over the required input to the post array

`$_POST['image'] = $_FILES['image']`

and then run the validation with just a callback, which does the actual validation using the upload library on the actual `$_FILES` item, but that seems a bit hacky.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let the callback check the $_FILES - no need to copy over the $_POST

```
public function _check_file($file)
{
          $this->load->library('upload');
          if ( ! $this->ci->upload->do_upload())
          {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_file', 'error');
                return FALSE;
          }
          else
          {
                    return TRUE;
          }
}
```

**edit: to clarify** - whilst the validation library only checks POST by default - when you run the callback YOU have access to FILES - so just check FILES in your callback. This is what I do and it works well.

Comment: Will the validation even run the callback if the field you have provided has no entry in $_POST?

Comment: good question - and the answer is 'yes' - because I am doing this EXACT thing. try it and you'll see

Comment: Ah sweet, I just assumed that it would try to be 'smart' and go, we don't have data so there is no point validating it!